# randomly reorder elements in an array without duplication

Tags: c++

I have a fixed array of sized nine and I am trying to reorder it randomly without duplication.

this is the following code:

```
class numbers{
    int randomIndexCount;
    public:
        void randomArray( int numArray[],int size){
            randomIndexCount = 0;               
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {   
                int RandomIndex = rand() % size;
                randomIndexCount++;
                numArray[i] = numArray[RandomIndex];
                cout << numArray[i] <<endl;                 
            }           
    }

    int main(){
        srand(time(0));
        int numArray[9]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0};
        numbers n;
        n.randomArray(numArray,9);
        return 0;
    }
```

So far I was able to reorder the array randomly with the given elements however I am unsure how to get rid of duplication. the output should be {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0} but in a random order.
I am unable to use the shuffle function and can only use rand. 
I am not sure how to remove duplicate entries

this is what I had in mind
1) with the given index check if that value already exist and if it does then skip this line "  numArray[i] = numArray[RandomIndex];". however this approach would not be efficient as im sure this would be too time consuming.
is there a way to remove duplicate values so my output is something like:

```
{0,1,0,6,2,0,5,3,4}
```

Comment: Use a Fisher-Yates shuffle algo: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/

Comment: Removed duplicated manually and use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: I am meant to create my own algorithm without using any shuffle functions

Comment: Is there any reason you want/need to create your own algorithm? Using the standard library it would be like 3 lines. You probably need to 1.) sort 2.) remove duplicates 3.) shuffle using Fisher-Yates-Shuffle

Comment: HashSet to give you distinct, then Fisher-Yates.

Comment: My unit is data structures and algorithms and the focus is on doing it outself

Comment: Sorry i was asking for help? You know to be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: The brute force solution is quite easy. Do you care about performance? If yes you should sort the data, to be more efficient in removing duplicates. Then shuffle it again. It may be good to write 3 seperate functions for this.

Comment: @ZachSaw be cool buddy, He is asking for help, we all go through this kind of thing.

Comment: @churill Note the problem description presents example data _with_ duplicates, so you're not allowed to remove them. The problem OP has is creating _unwanted_ duplicates by unwittingly overwriting some elements of the array with other elements of the same array.

Answer (score 1):

You should swap elements in this line `numArray[i] = numArray[RandomIndex];`, not assigning. This will duplicate data! Here's the swap:

```
int v = numArray[i];
numArray[i] = numArray[RandomIndex];
numArray[RandomIndex] = v;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are duplicating the elements with the assignement inside the for loop

```
numArray[i] = numArray[RandomIndex]
```

Instead asign the element to the position of the array, you need to swap those elements as follow:

```
class numbers
{
  int randomIndexCount;
public:
  void randomArray (int numArray[], int size)
  {
    randomIndexCount = 0;
    // Use srand with a time seed value in order to
    // have different results in each run of the programm
    srand (time (NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      {
    int swap = numArray[i];
    //take a random index from 0 to i  
    int j = rand () % (size);
      numArray[i] = numArray[j];
      numArray[j] = swap;
      cout << numArray[i] << endl;
      }
  }
};

int main ()
{
  int numArray[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0 };
  numbers n;
  n.randomArray (numArray, 9);
  return 0;
}
```

This will be the output that includes all then numbers in the array:

```
5
2
0
6
3
0
1
0
```

Comment: The output should contain all the numbers in the array in a random order 1-6 and 0,0,0

Comment: tested it out and still has duplicate numbers and only prints out 8 numbers instead of 9

Answer (score 1):

This loop scans positions from the end of the array towards its beginning and randomly selects a new item to be put at the current position. Items are chosen from positions not scanned yet.

This way every place is exactly once chosen to be filled with some item, and each item is exactly once placed in its final position (although, before this happens, it may be several times swapped out of places chosen for other elements).

It also guarantees no item disappears (gets overwritten) and no duplicates appear (no item is copied inadvertently) - if you have duplicates in input data, the same duplicates remain in the output (although permuted); if there are no duplicates, there will be no duplicates.

Additionally, if the `rand()` function has no bias, every item has the same chance to end at any chosen position, hence each possible permutation is equally probable as an output.

```
for (int i = size; i > 1; -- i)
{
    int swapIndex = rand() % i;

    int swap = numArray[swapIndex];
    numArray[swapIndex] = numArray[i-1];
    numArray[i-1] = swap;
}
```

Comment: this code is half correct, it removed duplication however only prints out 8 elements not 9

Comment: @willzz100 This code does print _nothing_, it only permutes an array.

Comment: @willzz100 I have expanded a description of the loop's properties, hopefully it is useful.